# Adding tasks to Windows scheduler with PHP

Tags: php, exec, scheduled-tasks

I'm unable to find any information on adding tasks to Windows Task Scheduler with PHP. I can use exec().

This has to work on IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Schedule Task has a command line utility called Schtasks you can use this utility to add your task to Scheduled task list.

Please go thru the URL for syntax of Schtasks
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772785%28WS.10%29.aspx#BKMK_run

Answer (score 3):

Syntax for schtasks

```
Schtasks /create /sc ScheduleType /tn TaskName /tr TaskRun [/s Computer [/u [Domain\]User [/p Password]]] [/ru {[Domain\]User | System}] [/rp Password] [/mo Modifier] [/d Day[,Day...] | *] [/m Month[,Month...]] [/i IdleTime] [/st StartTime] [/ri Interval] [{/et EndTime | /du Duration} [/k]] [/sd StartDate] [/ed EndDate] [/it] [/Z] [/F]
```

You can use

```
$cmd = 'schtasks /create blah blah blah...';
exec ($cmd);
```