# Php delay sending data for 5 minutes

Tags: php, linux, zend-framework

I have some data that are inserted to database after form submit. After they are inserted to databse I need to sed that data to email but I have to wait 5 minutes before I send them.

Is there anyway that I can wait for 5 minutes with, let say with sleep function. I do not want user to wait 5 minutes for script to be executed.

This is what I am thinking:

1) submit form and insert data to db

2) send inserted row id to some other script that runs somehow on server as process

3) after 5 minutes send email with script that is run as a process

4) if there is more then let say 50 ids on hold fire up new process and do steps from 3-4 again.

This is just what I am thinking.

I have no idea where to start.

Please give me some directions. I do not need redy to use solution.

I do not want to use cron job!!!

Comment: Why not use cron if it would work?

Comment: If you could explain why you need to wait 5 minutes, it might be easier for us to suggest a solution

Comment: I see you saying you don't want to use cron job, but wonder why. Otherwise you need to create a server process and set up a monitoring process to ensure the server process is running all the time.

Comment: It does not matter why I want to wait for 5 minutes. I want to wait for an hour on 10 minutes. Time is irelevant here.

Comment: I do not have any code.I do not seek any code, I just need suggestion on how to do this with let say pseudo code if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong answer in pseudo code is to

```
Put record in queue with timestamp eg a database
Write server process to monitor queue and see if 5 mins has passed
Send mail if 5 mins have passed.
Write monitoring system to monitor server process and ensure it is working.
```

The much better answer would be to use the linux at function if available or other pre-existing task scheduling system dependent on an unspecified platform. Scheduling tasks to occur at a certain time is exactly what you need to do and that is what these systems are designed to do.

Comment: I was able to solve this with help of AT linux daemon: echo "wget http://domain/script.php?email=me@me.com" | at now + 5 min.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule tasks that runs after 5 minutes as follows...

On Windows:

[Adding tasks to Windows scheduler with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913291/adding-tasks-to-windows-scheduler-with-php)

On Linux:

`shell_exec("echo 'date > /some/dir/date.txt' | at now + 1 minute");`

Answer (score -1):

Best Way You can Insert Your Form Data With Time Field Which Will Keep The Record Of Inserted Time. On the otherside You create A PHP file with `META refresh` of `30 SEC`  Which Will Check All records Which have matured with time of `5 Mintues` and do what you want to do and also mark the status for which action has been performed so that those records are not selected agian.